# I am unable to log error on mongoDB (Winston)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, logging, winston

I am trying to save error logs to mongoDB database but the logs don't get saved.
This is my transporter

```
module.exports = createLogger({
    transports:[

     ...         
     new transports.MongoDB({
            db : process.env.MONGO_URI,
            level: 'error',
            options: {
                useUnifiedTopology: true
            },
             collection: 'Server Logs',
             format: format.combine(
                format.timestamp(),
                format.json()
             )
         })
    ]
   });
```

Usage

```
app.listen(PORT, () => logger.info(`Connected to port ${PORT}`))

throw new Error("SOMEFDVSDFVS")

process.on("unhandledRejection", (error, promise) => {
    if(error){
        logger.error("Unhandled Promise Rejection Error :", error)
        process.exit(1)
    } else {
        logger.info("Promise :", promise)
    }
})
```

However if I change the level to `level:info` and I uncomment `throw new Error("SOMEFDVSDFVS")`  the logs is saved to the database

Atlas

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: you must be catching those error some ware in your code.  You need to log errors at there as you did in your unhandledRejection code. Best way world be creating errorhandling middleware and catch all errors of your application there. One more thing winston mongodb transport have one more property to log unhandled errors. check documents for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simulate it.
from the results that I tried, because the application stopped immediately due to *process.exit(1)*.

Then I give a few seconds timeout, to give a delay before the application stops and succeeds.

Here's my code snippet

```
process.on("uncaughtException", (ex) => {
    console.log("Error: Uncaught Exception," + ex.message);
    console.log("Error: Application will exit in 5 seconds...");
    logger.error("Error: Uncaught Exception.", ex);
    setTimeout(() => {
      process.exit(1);
    }, 5000);
  });

  process.on("unhandledRejection", (ex) => {
    console.log("Error: Unhandled Rejection," + ex.message);
    console.log("Error: Application will exit in 5 seconds...");
    logger.error("Error: Unhandled Rejection.", ex);
    setTimeout(() => {
      process.exit(1);
    }, 5000);
  });
```